# How to apply one HBase row filter atop of another HBase filter?

Tags: java, hbase

Let there are two HBase row [filters](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter.html): filterA, and filterB.
Is there any way to apply filterB only to rows 
accepted by filterA during the same scan.

Note that it differs from applying filter list of filterA and filterB.
For example, filterB passess only the first row it encounters.

And there are no possibility to incorporate logic of filterB
into filterA, because filters A and B are selected in runtime
from several available filters.

Comment: Can you elaborate why applying a FilterList of filterA and filterB would not be enough? To quote the documentation: "Implementation of Filter that represents an ordered List of Filters which will be evaluated ... FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL evaluates lazily: evaluation stops as soon as one filter does not include the Cell" http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html

Comment: Thank you Martin! Probably you are right, and FilterList is enough. I've overlooked the "evaluates lazily" remark in documentation.